# How can I access nested objects array with pre defined variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm trying to print out only the year data because I want to perform some functions on it. the q var is coming form a html form so we don't know what will be the value of q the user will decide:

```
filtered: [

          { Year: '2019', score1: 88 },
          { Year: '2020', score1: 89 },
          { Year: '2021', score1: 90 },
          { Year: '2022', score1: 91 },
          { Year: '2023', score1: 92 },
          { Year: '2023', score1: 100 }
        ]



    var q = "Year";
    for (let i = 0; i < filterd.length; i++) {
    console.log(filterd[i].q);
    }
```

```
  Output:
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
    undefined
```

Comment: No, I've tried the same method but i'm getting undefined output
This works fine: filtered[i].Year
But I need to pass q1 instead and its not working

Comment: It's not `filterd[i].q` but rather `filterd[i][q]`  (couldn't decide whether to use `filterd` or `filtered` because of the typo, but you know what I mean -- hopefully the typo wasn't the original problem.)

Answer (score 1):

From the [link I've added in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

```js
const filtered = [{
    Year: '2019',
    score1: 88
  },
  {
    Year: '2020',
    score1: 89
  },
  {
    Year: '2021',
    score1: 90
  },
  {
    Year: '2022',
    score1: 91
  },
  {
    Year: '2023',
    score1: 92
  },
  {
    Year: '2023',
    score1: 100
  }
]



var q = "Year";
for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
  console.log(filtered[i][q]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your snippet fixed:

```js
const filtered = [
  { Year: '2019', score1: 88 },
  { Year: '2020', score1: 89 },
  { Year: '2021', score1: 90 },
  { Year: '2022', score1: 91 },
  { Year: '2023', score1: 92 },
  { Year: '2023', score1: 100 },
];

const q = 'Year';

for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
  console.log(filtered[i][q]);
}
```

The reason your code did not work was because in each iteration of the loop, your code was looking for a property called `q` in each object of your filtered array, as opposed to what you wanted, which was `filtered[i]."Year"`. This wouldn't work the way you would want it to anyway, as a string here would be a syntax error.

As far as I'm aware, the **only** way to insert a variable into an object property call is to use the `[]` notation, which accepts a string to target an object property. So in each iteration of the loop in the previous snippet, what is actually being read is `filtered[i]["year"]`, which is valid syntax.

Now this works, but if the object is within your control, I would recommend sticking to property names that do not require the `[]` syntax, and in-fact, you do not need to do this in your example. Also, you can make the code  more readable. Consider the following snippet instead:

```js
const filtered = [
  { year: '2019', score1: 88 },
  { year: '2020', score1: 89 },
  { year: '2021', score1: 90 },
  { year: '2022', score1: 91 },
  { year: '2023', score1: 92 },
  { year: '2023', score1: 100 },
];

for (let value of filtered) {
  console.log(value.year);
}
```

In this example, you remove the need for the `[]` property call syntax and storing the `"year"` string in a variable by calling the property directly in the loop.

Additionally, you have a more readable `for...of` loop statement for targeting each object in the array, as opposed to one of those ancient `for (i, condition, iteration)` loops.

If your not too attached to either `var` or `const / let`, I would just stick to always using `const / let`, as its more consistent with "modern" JavaScript.

To learn about anything talked about here, MDN is (as always) the best place to start when learning anything web-dev. Here are some useful links relevant to what was talked about here:

- [MDN working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [MDN for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Hope this helps.